# Can't connect to kafka after updating from HDP 2.4 to HDP 2.5 on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, hortonworks-data-platform, kafka-producer-api

I had a kafka producer project implemented on Sandbox 2.4 via Virtual box but since implemented this project on AWS EC2 (using Hortonworks cloudbreak). This has led me to upgrade to HDP 2.5 therefore switching from kafka 9 to kafka 10. I made the necessary dependency and IP(localhost) changes but am getting `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information`

The kafkaBroker internal ip is 10.0.75.111 and the sample kafka producer is below

```
public void initialise() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.0.75.111:6667");  // replaced localhost
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<Integer, String>(props);
}
```

Kafka listener is `PLAINTEXT://localhost:6667`

After running the program it is returning the error message below

```
803862 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-14] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Initiating connection to node -1 at 10.0.75.111:6667.
824863 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-14] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector  - Connection with /10.0.75.111 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:51)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:73)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:309)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:229)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:134)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
824863 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-14] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Node -1 disconnected.
```

I would appreciate any help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending data to your AWS setup cluster, you need to use the external IP addresses. However, if you run from the network you can use both.

In your case you seem to be running from outside the network. Try running using the public IP from outside/internal from the inside. That should get you going.